I need instruction or to hire someone to find a hidden keyword on a webpage
I don't know a lot about this. However, there is a company that has definitely buried a keyword for my products name on its webpage so that it will rank on google. I have looked at source code and tried also through the inspect tool. Does anyone have any suggestions or can I hire someone to find it and then record their screen so that it will show how they are able to find the hidden keyword.
I need to be able to show this for court purposes. So if I understand the video I can realistically explain how it is being done.
Thanks,
Mike

If you need this for court purposes you really should speak to a lawyer, as most of us don't know the rules around collecting evidence.   Also, its not clear from your question - do the keywords appear in the source code or not?  If not, why do you say that the company has buried the products names on its website?

Thank you for the reply. I have talked to attorneys, they said if I can explain it and video, that they can use as evidence. As it is a civil case and not criminal. once i know how to do it myself i can use it. I feel the keyword is buried in  java script. I'm positive its there, I just can't find it. I have already filed a suit. I just am looking for evidence of the scope of the issue.

Finding this in Javascript is likely to be more complicated as the information may be buried in the Javascript, or - and I suspect this is more likely - an AJAX or similar call is made to populate the information from a dynamic database.

(I'll delete this comment soon)  I may have 10 minutes to spend scratching this itch.  Feel free to email me details of the site and the keywords and I'll see if I can find the keywords and if I can come up with a way this evidence can be reproduced - dgstack@my.host.net.nz if you don't want to post the specifics here.

You haven't given enough information to get a specific answer to your question.  However, some thoughts as to where I'd begin:

When you say "definitely", what is your evidence for this?  Is the keyword actually showing in the text snippet of the SERPs, or is their site just appearing when you search for it?  If the latter, they may not have your keyword on the page as Google recognises synonyms for keywords and uses things like backlink text in order to decide what to rank a page on.
Are you sure it isn't a sponsored link?  I believe you can advertise against a term that's not yours, but you shouldn't be using trademarks in your ad.
Have you tried loading the page as Googlebot?  If they are doing anything dodgy, they may be cloaking content.


If I type in the site:domain "keyword" it shows. then if I go into morningscore and have it analize keywords for that page it also shows up. However it is buried in coding or java script or something.

Does it also appear in Bing etc.?  If its just Google, look at the Googlebot option above for cloaking.

Google only index js that renders as html. The inspector should be showing you the rendered code, even if viewing source does not (though you may need to click links on the page for any content that loads on click).

Easiest way is to press F12. Then CTRL + F and type whatever word you are looking for of you think it is a word on a specific web page.
Depending on the site, looking at the code might not be very helpful. Example, if it is a dynamic site generated after the page load, the source might not show what you want.

Thanks for answering. it's definitely not sponsored. I have been attacked in the Google organic by approximately 40 domains. If I type in the site:domain "keyword" it shows. then if I go into morningscore.io and have it analyze keywords for that page it also shows up. However, it is buried in coding or Javascript or something. I have been under attack from this company. I have already filed a lawsuit. now I am gathering more evidence to show the scope of how they have attacked and the intent behind the attack. I just found this today. I tried inspect element.

@MikeSmith Javascript can be inspected with Firefox's Developer Tools. Right click on site > Inspect > "Debugger" tab > "Search" tab. It may be possible that Javascript is being called from another site but first you could look in the site's own Js.
